# Colours in InDesign different in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, print-design, cmyk

I've created a logo in Illustrator CC for print in CMYK color mode. I've saved it as a PNG to import into my flyer I'm creating in InDesign.

However, the colors appear different. The logo in Illustrator has a green that is a lot duller than the same green (in CMYK values) in InDesign. Will they print the same even if they don't appear that way?

Answer (score 6):

PNG does **not** support CMYK color.

If you want CMYK... do **not** use the PNG format.

And this ponders the question.. why are you even bothering with PNG at all? Just place the .ai file in InDesign. If you created the logo in Illustrator then *only* saved it as a PNG file, you essentially threw away all your work. Hopefully you saved the .ai file as well. Or at the very least a .pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as stated by Scott, use the AI file but even those could look different in InDesign on your screen. They DO print out the same. To triple check go to your INFO palette in both programs and zoom in and use the eye dropper and check your values, sometimes you catch an error but at least it is BEFORE you go to print! Good luck!